# Spring HATEOAS: change array name in _embedded using RelProvider

Tags: java, spring-boot, hateoas

I've read the following reference ([Spring HATEOAS & HAL: Change array name in _embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28834796/spring-hateoas-hal-change-array-name-in-embedded)) and I tried to change the array name in the `_embedded` tag.

I don't want to put any reference to the (Spring) framework in my domain object (using `@Relation`).

Nor I don't want to use a specific library (evo-inflector) in my build file.

I'm also using an `Assembler` to put the correct links in my response:

```
@Component
public class OrderModelAssembler
                implements RepresentationModelAssembler<ProductionOrder, EntityModel<ProductionOrder>> {

        @Override
        public EntityModel<ProductionOrder> toModel(ProductionOrder order) {
                var model = EntityModel.of(order);
                switch (order.getState()) {
                        case DRAFT:
                                model.add(linkTo(methodOn(ProductionOrderController.class).rename(order.getId(), null))
                                                .withRel(URIConstants.REL_RENAME));
                                model.add(linkTo(methodOn(ProductionOrderController.class).submit(order.getId()))
                                                .withRel(URIConstants.REL_SUBMIT));
                                break;
                        case SUBMITTED:
                                model.add(linkTo(methodOn(ProductionOrderController.class).accept(order.getId(), null))
                                                .withRel(URIConstants.REL_ACCEPT));
                                break;
                        case ACCEPTED:
                                break;
                }
           return model;
        }

        @Override
        public CollectionModel<EntityModel<ProductionOrder>> toCollectionModel(
                        Iterable<? extends ProductionOrder> entities) {

                var productionModel = StreamSupport
                        .stream(entities.spliterator(), false)
                        .map(this::toModel)
                        .toList();
                return CollectionModel.of(productionModel,
                                linkTo(methodOn(ProductionOrderController.class)
                                                .getAllOrders()).withSelfRel());
        }

}
```

I tried to add the following bean in my main class, but with no success.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = EnableHypermediaSupport.HypermediaType.HAL)
@Configuration
public class ProductionOrdersApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductionOrdersApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    LinkRelationProvider relProvider() {
        return new LinkRelationProvider() {
            @Override
            public LinkRelation getItemResourceRelFor(Class<?> type) {
                return LinkRelation.of("productionOrder");
            }

            @Override
            public LinkRelation getCollectionResourceRelFor(Class<?> type) {
                return LinkRelation.of("productionOrders");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I've read the section in the Hateoas guide, where the 4 possibilities are those I tried.

Can you explain how to modify the array name in the `_embedded` tag using the `RelProvider` interface in order to obtain the following result:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "productionOrders": [
            {
                "_links": {
                    "rename": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/productionOrders/46ceb9a6-e6d5-4be8-9534-c1f2348b7592/rename"
                    },
                    "submit": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/productionOrders/46ceb9a6-e6d5-4be8-9534-c1f2348b7592/submit"
                    }
                },
                "expectedCompletionDate": "1970-01-01",
                "id": "46ceb9a6-e6d5-4be8-9534-c1f2348b7592",
                "name": "A test order",
                "state": "DRAFT"
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/productionOrders"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Olivier